# SQL counting with condition

Tags: sql

If I have a table called Buildings.

```
 Room_No    Bldg Capacity 
    112     SCEN   23
    242     JBHT   25
    542     SCEN    4
    324     JBHT   24
```

What I want is to print out the Bldg name and the total number of rooms that have a capacity more than 20 in each building. So it is supposed to look like:

```
 Bldg   Total
  SCEN    1
  JBHT    2
```

Am I going on the right track:

```
 Select Bldg, Count(Capacity > 20) as Total from Buildings Group By Total Desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers seem overly complicated for this problem. The solution is rather simple:

```
SELECT Bldg, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM Buildings 
WHERE Capacity > 20 
GROUP BY Bldg
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/308a6/1

Comment: @lad2025 its a very clever solution if that is OP's requirements. dani please include that in the OP and in your example if it is a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `CASE`:

```
Select Bldg, Count(CASE WHEN Capacity > 20 THEN 1 END) as Total 
from Buildings 
Group By Bldg
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```

---

If you are using `Postgresql` you could rewrite it as:

```
Select Bldg, Count(1) FILTER(WHERE Capacity>20) as Total 
from Buildings 
Group By Bldg
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/DOJB86587)**

Comment: or `Having Capacity > 20`

Comment: I changed the question so your answer would be correct.